# I can't get heading information

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm trying to get heading information using ios 4.3 on an iphone 4. I have my delegate set correctly but the following delegate method is not being called. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

> - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager
>     *)manager didUpdateHeading:
>           (CLHeading *)newHeading*)newHeading {
>
>   [manager setDelegate:self];
>
>   NSLog(@" I'm updating the location information now");
>
>   [manager startUpdatingHeading];
>
>   NSLog(@" heading info %@",newHeading); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're only telling the Location Manager that you want it to issue updates from within the function it calls when it issues updates, so there's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem here.  Move the calls to `-setDelegate:` and `-startUpdatingHeading` to someplace where they're sure to get called, like `-viewWillAppear` or `init`.  Make sure that the code is actually being executed.

Comment: Since I was using a delegate method why wasn't it being called by default? I actually had the delegate set in another method as well as the one above.

Comment: You have to call `-startUpdatingHeading` before any delegate messages will be called. Or possibly you just put that code somewhere it wasn't getting executed?